# Topological properties that aren't conserved over homotopy?

Tags: algebraic-topology

The problem is asking to list half a dozen topological properties that aren't preserved under Homotopy.

I can only think of cardinality (contractible spaces), compactness($\Bbb R^n$ is contractible), and interval type (open vs closed both contractible) but I'm struggling to find three other examples.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Cardinality is a rather silly example but it fits the bill.

Comment: For manifolds, orientability isn't preserved.

Comment: Consider properties of maps too

Comment: Completeness is not even preserved under homeomorphisms.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Dimension is a very important topological invariant which is not preserved under homotopy.

Comment: As in a cylinder is homotopic to a circle, yet they're not homeomorphic?

Comment: Exactly, or more simply $\mathbb R^n$ is homotopy equivalent to a point.

Comment: On the other hand, homotopy is already a pretty good invariant. In fact, Poincaré himself was thinking that if two closed manifolds have the same homotopy groups then they are homeomorphic !

Answer (score 10):

Another property which is not preserved is metrizability. Any real topological vector space is contractible but not all are metrizable.

Answer (score 8):

Few more example:

- Local connectivity.
- Hausdorff.
- Compact.
- Second countable.

Answer (score 6):

Another topological properties not preserved under homotopy are the separation properties $T_0$, $T_1$ and $T_2$ (more known as Hausdorff).

> From levap's answer, it follows that $T_0$, $T_1$ and $T_2$ are not preserved as there are real topological spaces which are neither $T_0$, $T_1$ or $T_2$.